# How can I remove notifications icon from windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, user-interface

I find this especially icon annoying, because I never use it, how can I remove it from taskbar? The right one in the image is the one im talking about
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaLRo.png)

Comment: That is the icon that shows notifications of all kinds and so far as I know, it is built in and not removable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either remove the action center via settings in windows 10 or via the GPO:

1.Settings-->Turn system icons on or off

[image]

2.Search "Edit group policy"--->User Configuration, Administrative Templates, and Start Menu and Taskbar,Remove Notifications and Action Center

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Taskbar --> Taskbar Settings --> Turn System Icons On Or Off --> Action Center